# Where to find my d drive files in Ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

I installed Ubuntu from windows 8 and selected option to format just windows 8. But after full installation of Ubuntu I can't even find my d drive files. 
It contains very important files. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "option to format just windows 8?" That could be very bad news.

Comment: It had option "replace windows 8 with Ubuntu..."

Comment: It appears that you wiped out your windows install by choosing that option. If you wanted to keep it you should have chosen the "alongside" option.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I actually formatted my whole laptop

Answer (score 1):

Your "d" drive will now be something like /dev/sda4 or so, depending on your partition layout. You can do "sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt", where 4 can be changed to the partition number, to mount the partition on /mnt so you can see the contents with "ls /mnt". When done with that partition, or if that one is the wrong one, type "umount /dev/sda4" to  unmount it.

Comment: The Day drive is probably erased, if it was not a physical drive but a partition.

Comment: Probably, spaced on that.

Comment: There is no as such folder Dev/sd4. I searched each and every folder in it but can't find what I want. Please help!